# Samsung SSD: GParted can see, partition and format but Win7 won't initialize disk (CRC error)

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ssd, gparted, intel-rst

I have a 240GB Samsung SSD830. Pulled from working PC. Up to date firmware.

On attaching to 2nd working PC, Win7 states disk must be initialized, but fails with CRC error when attempting to do so, regardless of whether MBR or GPT is selected.

Intel RST pops up in notification area to state disk is part of a RAID array and cannot be accessed.  This classification is not correct.  The disk was once part of a RAID0 over a year ago, but was removed from the array and has been successfully used as a single drive ever since.

Samsung diagnostic tools can see the disk as a hardware device but cannot access it, other than to read SMART data (no problems highlighted).

After failing to get any success with Win7, I booted from GParted live CD.

In GParted I successfully removed the existing partitions and repartitioned with single primary partition - unformatted, with intention of later formatting this as NTFS in Win7.

On returning to Win7 to format, same as before: virtual disk manager states disk must be initialized, then CRC error.

Back into GParted.  Repartition with single primary and format as ext4.  Formatted partition is accessible from Linux Mint on same PC seemingly with no issues.  Back into Win7 - still saying drive must be initialized.

I half suspect RST is getting in the way with its false reports about the drive being part of a RAID set, but I know zilch about RST so I can't be even remotely sure.  All features and functions are grayed out when I select that drive in the RST front end.

I don't currently have access to any other machines to try it in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this sorted by performing an ATA Secure Erase.

I bought a copy of Parted Magic to do this via its fairly straightforward GUI as it's not something I'd be confident doing via CLI on the first go, but I believe it can be done in a number of different ways.